# What is the DNS Record logged by kubedns?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Google Container Engine and I'm noticing entries like the following in my logs

```
 {
    "insertId": "1qfzyonf2z1q0m",
    "internalId": {
      "projectNumber": "1009253435077"
    },
    "labels": {
      "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "710923338689591312",
      "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-gas2016-4fe456307445d52d-worker-pool-",
      "compute.googleapis.com/resource_type": "instance",
      "container.googleapis.com/cluster_name": "gas2016-4fe456307445d52d",
      "container.googleapis.com/container_name": "kubedns",
      "container.googleapis.com/instance_id": "710923338689591312",
      "container.googleapis.com/namespace_name": "kube-system",
      "container.googleapis.com/pod_name": "kube-dns-v17-e4rr2",
      "container.googleapis.com/stream": "stderr"
    },
    "logName": "projects/cml-236417448818/logs/kubedns",
    "resource": {
      "labels": {
        "cluster_name": "gas2016-4fe456307445d52d",
        "container_name": "kubedns",
        "instance_id": "710923338689591312",
        "namespace_id": "kube-system",
        "pod_id": "kube-dns-v17-e4rr2",
        "zone": "us-central1-f"
      },
      "type": "container"
    },
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "textPayload": "I0718 17:05:20.552572       1 dns.go:660] DNS Record:&{worker-7.default.svc.cluster.local. 6000 10 10  false 30 0  }, hash:f97f8525\n",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-18T17:05:20.000Z"
  }
```

Is this an actual error or is the severity incorrect? Where can I find the  definition for the struct that is being printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The severity is incorrect. This is some tracing/debugging that shouldn't have been left in the binary, and has been removed since 1.3 was cut. It will be removed in a future release.

See also: [Google container engine cluster showing large number of dns errors in logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487428/google-container-engine-cluster-showing-large-number-of-dns-errors-in-logs/38494636#38494636)